# Jquery: $.getJSON with different url port

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use `$.getJSON` with a local app calling another local app on a different port.
For example my app is running on `localhost:3000`, but I want to make a `$.getJSON` call to another app running on `localhost:3001`, in firebug it returns red with a 200 response, but with no data in the response.  Is there a way to do this?  I tried this....

```
 $.getJSON('http://localhost:3001/dashboard/widgets/marketing_efficiency_gauge.json',
 {   key: 'value' }, function(data){

 alert(data)

  });
```

Edit: for clarity there are two rails apps involved one on localhost:3000 another on localhost:3001

Second edit: here is the json response for localhost:3001 when I hit it with a browser (say firefox) https://gist.github.com/willfults/7665299

Comment: You confirmed the same URL works in the browser, manually?

Comment: Yes, it works manually.

Comment: why you wrote alert(data) two times? Its an error in the callback!

Comment: it is another web app running, that is why i need the full url

Comment: @Paolo: that was a typo, but that wouldn't matter, it would just alert twice

Comment: ok people lol i removed the second alert, same result haha

Comment: Your problem is due to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). To fix it, you'll need to enable [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the localhost:3001 service.

Comment: there is an "edit" button to fix errors so contributors can focus on the problem

Comment: @Mac Aww, I was about to say that. But given that Firebug does receive something, I'm not sure if this already has been considered.

Comment: @Paolo: already did friend thanks :)

Comment: @thenewseattle, the json is valid here is the response when i hit it with a browser - https://gist.github.com/willfults/7665299

Comment: @HelloWorld Can you please confirm that you have taken precautions regarding CORS, as Mac mentioned above?

Comment: @Derija93: this is most likely a CORS issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) prevents JavaScript scripts from making HTTP requests to different domains. For the purposes of SOP, a URL with the same hostname but different ports (as is the case here) is still considered to be a different domain, and hence requests are not permitted.

What typically happens in such cases is that the browser actually does make the request over the network, but drops the response and sends an error result to the JavaScript.

To fix this, you'll need to implement [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) on the `localhost:3001` service. In a nutshell, this entails adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to responses listing the domains which are permitted to make cross-domain requests to the service. That is, in this case adding a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost:3000` header to the response from the `localhost:3001` service should allow things to work as you expect.

Incidentally, this is why the browser makes the request but drops the result: it needs to request the headers from the server in order to determine whether the JavaScript is allowed to make the request or not (i.e. it needs to check if there's a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header in the response). Why a `HEAD` request isn't sufficient, I don't know.

The other alternative is to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). This is potentially simpler to implement on the server side, but has the disadvantages of only working for `GET` requests, and requiring slightly trickier coding on the client side.

Comment: @HelloWorld If you only need to do GET requests, implementing jsonp would probably be the easiest solution.

Comment: @JasonP: yes I only need get requests at the moment, researching how to do that now :)

Comment: @JasonP: that's another good alternative, which I have added to the answer.

Comment: This worked, so many options, if someone finds this and is using rails you can use this - http://www.tsheffler.com/blog/?p=428